# Prove that $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 1^-} rf(r)|f'(r)|=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^0[0,1]\cap\mathcal{C}^2(0,1)$ and satisfy

- Boundary Condition: $f(0)=0=f(1)$
- Positive: $f(r)>0,\quad r\in(0,1)$
- Finite Energy: $\int_0^1\left(r(f')^2+\dfrac{f^2}{r}\right)dr<\infty$

I want to prove the 2nd problem. I include the first to show what I am able to do.

1. $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 0^+} rf(r)|f'(r)|=0$
2. $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 1^-} rf(r)|f'(r)|=0$.

I am able to show the first one is true via a contradiction. However, the approach does not work for the second one.

Here is the proof for the first one. Suppose 1 is not true, but the limit exists, i.e.,
$$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 0^+} rf(r)|f'(r)|=L>0.$$

By the definition of the limit, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $r_0\in(0,1)$ such that $$\big|rf(r)|f'(r)|-L\big|<\epsilon\quad\forall r\in(0,r_0).$$
We then have
$$L-\epsilon<rf(r)|f'(r)|<L+\epsilon\quad\forall r\in(0,r_0).$$
Now, we can choose $\epsilon=\dfrac{L}{2}>0$ to get
$$\dfrac{L}{2}<rf(r)|f'(r)|\quad\forall r\in(0,r_0).$$

Then dividing by $r$ and integrating on $(0,r_0)$, we arrive at
$\infty=\int_0^{r_0}\dfrac{L}{2r}dr\leq\int_0^{r_0}f(r)|f'(r)|dr\leq\left(\int_0^{r_0}\dfrac{(f(r))^2}{r}dr\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^{r_0}r(f')^2dr\right)^{1/2}<\infty$, a contradiction to the finite energy condition.

If I approach the second one via a contradiction, it is clear that $f'(r)\rightarrow\infty$ as $r\rightarrow 1$ and, consequently, should have a contradiction to the finite energy condition. But, I am unable to establish rigorous proof.

Comment: Dear OP, I think we need some more conditions on $f$. You obviously assume that $f$ is differentiable and hence continuous. But continuous on which set? $[0,1]$ or $(0,1)$? Also the derivative exists on what set? Is it continuous? Another crucial question, is $f$ bounded?

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos Thank you for your comments. I edited the question to answer your question.

Comment: This clarifies many things! Thanks!

Comment: I do not get why you keep the factor $r.$ It tends to $1.$ Also the problem in the title is equivalent to $\lim_{r\to 1^-}f(r)f'(r)=0.$

Comment: So if @DamianPavlyshyn post is correct, where is the error in the proof of (1.) above ? Note: there seems to be a missing square on $f(r)$ in $\left(\int_0^{r_0}\dfrac{f(r)}{r}dr\right)^{1/2}$

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni The existence of an $\epsilon>0$ and $r_0$ such that $rf(r)|f'(r)|\geq\epsilon$ is not valid.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni I started to review this problem again and I am no longer convinced that there is a mistake in my proof. So, I am rewriting the proof with more details and going over the provided counter example. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Going over your comment and after some reviewing, I believe that $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 1^-}$ is not equivalent to  $\liminf\limits_{r\rightarrow 1}$, since the limit inf always exists and the one-sided limit may not. Do you agree?

Comment: I agree concerning $\liminf.$ . In your original question $\limsup$ has been mentioned  at the point   $1.$

Comment: @VariationalPrinciples The fun is that, when the counter-example was posted, I was trying to prove the limit on $1$ by a change of variable that would transform it into the limit on $0$, which you had already proven. There is a small difference between them however, and I did not persevere once the counter-example was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had previously posted an incorrect proof of (1.) and (2.) - thanks to @ryszard-szwarc for pointing out the error!

In fact, nether (1.) nor (2.) hold in general.

We will first construct a function $g \in C^0[0, 1] \cap C^2(0, 1)$ such that $g(0) = 0$ and $g' \in L^{2 + \epsilon}(0, 1)$ but $\limsup_{x\rightarrow 0} g(x) |g'(x)| = \infty$.

To this end, consider a smooth function $\varphi$ that vanishes outside $[-1, 1]$ and satisfies $0 \leq \varphi \leq 1, \varphi(0) = 1, \int \varphi(x) dx = 1$.
Using this, define
\begin{align*}
  h(x)
  = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n\, \varphi(n^4(x - 1/n)).
\end{align*}
(we start the indexing from $n=2$ so that the supports of all of the summands are disjoint).

Now, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 h(x)^{2 + \epsilon} dx
\leq \sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{2 + \epsilon} \int_0^1 \varphi(n^4(x - 1/n)) dx
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-2 + \epsilon}
< \infty,
\end{align*}
so that $h \in L^{2 + \epsilon}[0, 1]$ for $\epsilon < 1$.
This means that $H(x) = \int_0^x h(x) dx$ is in $C^0[0, 1]$ with $H'(x) = h(x)$ and $H(0) = 0$.
Now, we define
$$
g(x) = x^{2/3} + H(x).
$$

This satisfies all the desired conditions on $g$ with $g' \in L^{2 + \epsilon}(0, 1)$ for $\epsilon < 1$.
However, we have that, since $h(1/n) = n$,
\begin{align*}
g(1/n) g'(1/n)
= (n^{-2/3} + H(1/n))\Bigl(\frac{2}{3} n^{1/3} + h(1/n)\Bigr) 
\geq n^{1/3}
\rightarrow \infty
\end{align*}

---

Now, we can construct a counterexample that violates both (1.) and (2.).
Let $\Lambda$ be a smooth function such that
\begin{align*}
\Lambda(x)
= \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } x < 1/3, \\
0 &\text{if } x > 2/3.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then define
\begin{align*}
f(x) = x^{-1/2} g(x) \Lambda(x) + g(1 - x) \Lambda(1 - x),
\end{align*}
which satisfies the smoothness, positivity and $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ requirements.

The significance of $g' \in L^{2 + \epsilon}(0, 1)$ is then that we conclude from Jensen's inequality that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^x g'(y)^{2 + \epsilon} dy
&= x\cdot \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x g'(y)^{2 + \epsilon} dy \\
&\geq x \Bigl[\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x g'(y) dy\Bigr]^{2 + \epsilon} \\
&= g(x)^{2 + \epsilon} x^{-1 - \epsilon}, \\
g(x)
&\leq \lVert g' \rVert_{2 + \epsilon}\, x^{\frac{1}{2} + \eta},
\end{align*}
where $\eta = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\epsilon}{2 + \epsilon}> 0$.
In particular, this means that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x^{-1/2}g(x) = 0$ so that $f(0) = 0$, and also that $g(x)/x \in L^2(0, 1)$.

For the finite energy condition, we have that, for $x < 1/3$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x)^2}{x}
&= \frac{g(x)^2}{x^2}, \\
f'(x)
&= -\frac{1}{2} x^{-3/2} g(x) + x^{-1/2} g'(x), \\
f'(x)^2
&\leq \frac{1}{2} x^{-3} g(x)^2 + 2 x^{-1} g'(x)^2, \\
x f'(x)^2
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \frac{g(x)^2}{x^2} + 2 g'(x)^2.
\end{align*}

For the interval $[2/3, 1]$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x)^2}{x}
&= \frac{g(1 - x)^2}{x}
\leq \frac{3}{2} g(1 - x)^2, \\
x f'(x)^2
&= x g'(1 - x)^2
\leq g'(1 - x)^2
\end{align*}

Last, $f$ is continuous on $[1/3, 2/3]$ and so is bounded on this inteval,

From the above, we have bounded the energy integrand above with a combination of the $L^2$ functions $g'(x), g(x)/x$ over the whole interval $[0, 1]$ so that we conclude
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{1} \Bigl(x f'(x)^2 + \frac{f(x)^2}{2}\Bigr) dx < \infty. 
\end{align*}

But we have that, on the one hand, when $x < 1/3$,
\begin{align*}
x f(x) f'(x)
&= x (x^{-1/2} g(x)) \Bigl(-\frac{1}{2} x^{-3/2} g(x) + x^{-1/2} g'(x)\Bigr) \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{g(x)^2}{x} + g(x) g'(x), \\
\frac{1}{n} f\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr) f'\Bigl(\frac{1}{n} \Bigr) 
&= -\frac{n}{2} g(1/n)^2 + g(1/n) g'(1/n) \\
&\rightarrow \infty,
\end{align*}
while on the other hand, when $x > 2/3$,
\begin{align*}
x f(x) f'(x)
&= - x g(1 - x) g'(1 - x), \\
\Bigl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\Bigr) f\Bigl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\Bigr) f'\Bigl(1 - \frac{1}{n} \Bigr) 
&= \Bigl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\Bigr) g(1/n) g'(1/n) \\
&\rightarrow \infty.
\end{align*}

Thus for this $f$,
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{r\rightarrow 0} r f(r) |f'(r)|
= \limsup_{r\rightarrow 1} r f(r) |f'(r)|
= \infty
\end{align*}

Comment: In the proof of  Theorem you claim that if $g(x):=x^{1/2}f(x)=o(x)$  then   $ g'$ is bounded near $0.$  Or I misunderstood your way of reasoning.

Comment: The proof of Theorem is incorrect. If a function $g$ is continuously differentiable on $(0,1/2]$ and Lipschitz at $0,$ it does not need to be Lipschitz on $[0,1/2].$

Comment: Ah yes, you're right - thanks for pointing this out! And yeah, I can see now that it's totally possible for $f'(x)$ to not be $O(x^{-1/2})$. I'll take this down while I see if this argument can be fixed.

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn I am still having difficulty seeing where I went wrong in my proof for 1. I updated it with a few more details.

Comment: @VariationalPrinciples You've proved that if the limit as $r\rightarrow 0^+$ exists, then it must be $0$. This is correct, however the negation of "the limit is $0$" includes the cases where the function diverges to infinity (as in my counter-example) or oscillates (I believe that this is also possible, but it's even more annoying to construct). In particular, in the infinite limit case, it is impossible to choose an $\epsilon$ such that $|r f(r) |f'(r)| - L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn Thank you! It make's sense now.

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn I just checked that if we assume the limit goes to $\infty$, then we still get a contradiction to the infinite energy condition since by definition for any $M\in\mathbb{R}$ there would be an $r_0\in(0,1)$ such that $rf(r)f'(r)>M$ for all $r\in(0,r_0)$. Then dividing by $r$ and integrating gives the contradiction to the finite energy condition. Can you please remark as to why this is not correct?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right - it's also not possible for $r f(r) f'(r)$ to diverge to $+\infty$ as $r \rightarrow 0$. I misspoke when I said that my example diverges to $\infty$. In fact, only the limsup is $\infty$ as $r\rightarrow 0$, and I'm pretty sure that the lminf is $0$ so that the function oscillates near $0$ and $1$. It's generally very difficult to control oscillation using conditions on integrals, since the oscillation can happen on very small intervals (as in this case) without affecting the integral much.

Comment: Actually, your proof strategy does prove that the liminf must be 0, because it's in the case that $r f(r) f'(r)$ is above some threshold for all $r \in (0, r_0)$ (ie $\liminf > 0$) that you get the contradiction.